# Scheduled JobService after device Reboots

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

Does scheduled JobService(JobScheduler api or firebase jobdispather) , which has not been executed due to specified conditions are not met automatically rescheduled after device reboots? Or we need to reschedule .

Answer (score 0):

Might i suggest if you want your task to work on devices older than lollipop you should use GCM Task service which i believe uses JobService on lollipop and above to get the job done but will use an alternate implementation on older devices.

http://blog.fossasia.org/working-with-gcm-task-service-on-android/

with that out of the way you can clearly see you can create a one off task or a recurring task in the example posted. if your one off task fails though yes you will need to reschedule it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), you can specify the persistence of the request when you build it using [setPersisted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)).

For [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), use [setLifeTime()](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/Job.java#L257). Values are `FOREVER` and `UNTIL_NEXT_REBOOT`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for `Firebase JobDispather`. Here is an issue from bug tracker - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/101

Comment: Make use of this library: https://github.com/evernote/android-job I find it to work well